# Запрос с условием и объединением

Tags: mysql, php, sql

```
SELECT * FROM message INNER JOIN users  ON id = message.mfromu
```

Сформировал такой запрос, теперь задаюсь вопросом: как сделать так, чтобы выводило из таблицы `message` только то, где `mid=$mid`, где mid - id сообщения, а $mid - id полученный из GET запроса.

Comment: @SnikersSurgut, не забывайте принимать верные ответы!!!

Comment: Почитайте где-нибудь про `WHERE` и предотвращение SQL-инъекций.

Comment: `"select * from message where mid=".(int)$_GET['id'];`

Comment: @KaZaца: `(int)` -- это хитро :) Если, конечно, тип у `id` и правда `int`.

Comment: У меня не зря стоит $mid, так как в самом верху кода всё уже проверено.

Comment: @SnikersSurgut, я пишу `id = $_POST['uid']`, и это никак не означает что может быть sql-injection.

Comment: в качестве совета просто, хотите принимайте к сведению - хотите нет: называйте переменные по человечески. Что такое mfromu в таблице? Что такое $mid? В вашем коде должно быть масса комментариев к этим названиям!

По сабжу ниже.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM first_table
INNER JOIN second_table ON (second_table.key = first_table.key)
WHERE first_table.field = value
```

в общем виде как-то так